# Create HTML table from txt file

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have the following attempt at my function, but it's just printing out everything in the contacts.txt file on one line...

```
function contactsTable(){

  $file = fopen("contacts.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
  echo "<tr><th>";
  while (!feof($file)){
    echo "<tr><th>";
      $data = fgets($file); 
      echo "<tr><td>" . str_replace(',','</td><td>',$data) . '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo "<tr><th>";
  echo '</table>';
  fclose($file);
}
```

contacts.txt example like this;

```
Row 1 is headers --->  [value1, value2, value3, value4]
Row 2 is data --->     [value5, value6, value7, value8]
```

Is it possible to change my function so that Row 1 is using `<th>` tags so they are formatted as headers and the rest of the rows go into `<td>` tags for table data? I've tried to amend the logic but can't seem to get it.

TIA

Comment: You can use the javascript fetch method for this.

Comment: if the header is known just put a line above your while loop and have a look at [fgetcsv] (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php) and the example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your `contactsTable()` function that prints the first `contacts.txt` line as table header and some basic HTML formatting for easy reading/debugging.

```php
function contactsTable() {
  $file = fopen('contacts.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open file!');
  $row = 0;

  echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;

  
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $row++;
    $data = fgets($file);

    if ($row === 1) {
      echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<th>' . str_replace(',', '</th><th>', $data) . '</th>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
      echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '<td>' . str_replace(',', '</td><td>', $data) . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
      echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;

  fclose($file);
}
```